# Sending message from server to multiple clients in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, synchronization, client-server

I am creating a chat server program, I have used the code written here 
http://makemobiapps.blogspot.com/p/multiple-client-server-chat-programming.html
and I want to add some change in it, I am trying to let the server send a message to all connected clients. I have add this code. but it did not work. it send the message to clients but in incorrect way, like it sends the message to only one client. Then it stops accepting any client to  connect to the network.

This is the code that I add using Scanner

```
while (true) {  
    try {
    int i = 0; 
    clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 
    for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
      if (threads[i] == null) {                           
        (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
        break;
      }        
    }
  // this my code I add to broadcast a message to all clients
    if(!in.nextLine().isEmpty() ){
      for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
      PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      os.println("Server :"+in.next());
        }
    }

    if (i == maxClientsCount) {
      PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
      os.close();
      clientSocket.close();
    }        
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
  }
```

please any idea it will help me :)
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
```

Here you are looping over `i` between 0 and `maxClientsCount`.

```
  PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
```

Here you are writing to the most recently accepted socket, `maxClientsCount-1` times, and completely ignoring `i`.

```
  os.println("Server :"+in.next());
```

Here you are reading a new token from your `Scanner` every time around the loop.

Not much of this makes sense. Surely what you mean is:

```
String line = in.nextLine();
if(!line.isEmpty() ){
  for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
    if (threads[i] == null)
      continue;
    PrintStream os = new PrintStream(threads[i].getSocket().getOutputStream());
    os.println("Server :"+line);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct it did what I want. But, one problem arise here. When the connection starts, the clients wait for the server to enter some data, then they can send messages to each other. I hope you get me right!

Comment: I know what it does. You haven't stated what it is that you *want* it to do.